# Javascript replace exact match w/o specialchars

Tags: javascript, regex

```
bar foo: baz qux bar foo baz foo; bar
```

In this string I want to replace only the **foo**

I tried `\bfoo\b` but it replaces all occurrences. How can I replace the exact word with regex?

Comment: Which foo do you want to replace? The first, second, third?

Comment: I want to replace the one which does not have any special characters. The string above is just an example. Foo can be located anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"bar foo: baz qux bar foo baz foo; bar".replace(/(^|\s)foo(?!\S)/g, "$1hello")
```

The cleanest solution would be to use look-behind; unfortunately JavaScript doesn't support that. As a workaround, we capture the preceding whitespace character (or beginning of string) and re-insert it with the replacement (that's the `$1` part).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you just want to replace the one with spaces around it. For that, just do `/ foo /`, with spaces.

`\b` matches words, and punctuation is considered word delimiters.

To match it if it's at the beginning or end too, i would use a lookahead: `/(?=^|\s)foo(?=\s|$)/`

Comment: foo can be anywhere in the string. And If it is at the end  `/ foo /` won't work.

Comment: I added a solution for that.

Comment: @Scimonster Your lookahead version doesn't actually match anything.